# Как из хендшейка достать сам хеш пароля?

Tags: linux, безопасность, wifi, wireshark, handshake

У меня есть CAP файл через aircrack проверил и он пишет WPA(1 handshake), Смотрел через Wireshark не понял где именно там сам хеш пароля.

Как достать хеш пароля из cap файла?

Comment: По идее его там быть не должно.

Comment: @user7860670 но aircrack же его как то проверяет по словарю. просто хочу его достать чтобы сторонними программами поискать его